# Which they may not be using anymore

Tags: grammar

Let's say your giving a compliment to bazaar sellers.

> You:''bazaar is a smart move for the sellers. It teaches them to be productive by selling things, rather than just stock clothes in their house, **and which they may not be using anymore''**....

Is the bold ***clause grammatical***? Pls. Help

Answer (score 1):

To make it grammatically correct, get rid of the "and."  Unfortunately, this leads to some ambiguity; a native speaker might interpret this to mean that the house is no longer used, rather than the clothing.  I would say,

> It teaches them to be productive by selling many different things, rather than just the unused clothing in their houses.

Comment: I knew it! In my gut there's something wrong in my sentences. Thx very much! However, can I ask why did you use 'clothing' instead of 'clothes', should you really omit the 'stock' verb?